# Make a Node js Restful API uninterrupted

Tags: node.js, rest, nohup

I built a node JS API that I use in an application. That API returns results from a database.

How could I do to make that API uninterrupted? Indeed, I used a nohup node index.js to run the webservice but it stops quite frequently..

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are about a gazillion reasons a process can "be interrupted", aka crash. You don't want to have an uncrashable process, rather one that is restarted automatically when crashed.

Have a look at [pm2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2) for this.